# Generate pdf files with Weasyprint, save in zip file, send that zip file to client and present it for download

Tags: javascript, python, django, zip, weasyprint

Let me break down my requirement. Here's what I'm doing right now.

**1. Generate PDF files from HTML**

for this I'm using Weasyprint as following:

```
lstFileNames = []
for i, content in enumerate(lstHtmlContent):
    repName = 'report'+ str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.pdf'
    lstFileNames.append("D:/Python/Workspace/" + repName)

    HTML(string=content).write_pdf(target=repName,
        stylesheets=[CSS(filename='/css/bootstrap.css')])
```

all files names, with paths, are saved in `lstFileNames`.

**2. Create a zip file with pdf files generated by weasyprint**

for this I'm using zipfile

```
zipPath = 'reportDir' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.zip'
myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, 'w') 
with  myzip:
    for f in lstFileNames:
        myzip.write(f)
```

**3. Send zip file to client for download**

```
resp = HttpResponse(myzip, content_type = "application/x-zip-compressed")

resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'myzip.zip'
```

**4. Open file for downloading via Javascript**

```
var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/x-zip-compressed'});
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(fileURL);
```

***Problems***

**1.** While the zip file is successfully received at front end, after I try to open it, it gives the following error:

> The archive is in either unknown format or damaged

Am I sending the file wrong or is my Javascript code the problem?

**2.** Is there a way to store all pdf files in list of byte arrays and generate zip files with those byte array and send it to the client? I tried that with weasyprint but the result was same `damaged file`.

**3.** Not exactly a problem but I haven't been able to find it in weasyprint docs. Can I enforce the path to where the file should be saved?

Problem # 1 is of extreme priority, rest are secondary. I would like to know if I'm doing it right i.e. generating pdf files and sending their zip file to client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you open the zip file on the server?

Comment: i can open it manually, by going to the directory where its saved. PDF files in it are also opening

Comment: what happens if you just redirect to the url of the zip file, e.g. `window.location.href = 'link/to/file.zip';`? (move the zip file to a publicly available tmp folder)

Comment: It doesn't work. What i'm sending from server isn't a url

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach would be to move the zip file to a public directory and then send that location to the client (e.g. json formatted), i.e.:

```
publicPath = os.path.join('public/', os.path.basename(zipPath))
os.rename(zipPath, os.path.join('/var/www/', publicPath))

jsonResp = '{ "zip-location": "' + publicPath + '" }'

resp = HttpResponse(jsonResp, content_type = 'application/json');
```

Then in your client's javascript:

```
var res = JSON.parse(response);
var zipFileUrl = '/' + res['zip-location'];

window.open(zipFileUrl, '_blank');
```

`'/' + res['zip-location']` assumes that your page lives in the same folder as the `public` directory (so `http://example.com/public/pdf-files-123.zip` points to `/var/www/public/pdf-files-123.zip` on your file system).

You can clean up the `public` directory with a cron job that deletes all the `.zip` files in there that are older than an hour or so.

Comment: note: this is not tested, it's just to give you an idea

Comment: That's the first thing that I tried actually. Sending file location to the client to open. I couldn't figure out how to map an absolute path like `D:/reports/report.zip` to server path like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/report.zip`. If I send the path as is it just adds the absolute path at the end of url.

Comment: if it's just for local use, you can use the [file protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731(v=vs.85).aspx), i.e. `file:///D:/reports/report.zip`. What server do you use to host the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have exited the `with` block the filehandle is closed. You should reopen the file (this time with open) and use `read()` to pass the contents to `HttpResponse` instead of passing the filehandle itself.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, 'w') as myzip
    for f in lstFileNames:
        myzip.write(f)
with open(zipPath, 'r') as myzip:
    return HttpResponse(myzip.read(), content_type = "application/x-zip-compressed")
```

If that works, then you can use a `StringIO` instance instead of a filehandle to store the zip file. I'm not familiar with Weasyprint so I don't know whether you can use `StringIO` for that.

Comment: opening file and assigning it to httpresponse gives error: `'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 194: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: I fixed that by adding `rb` in open file line. Now it opens the zip file that gives error of `unexpected end of archive`

Comment: Did you remember to use `myzip.read()`? I said to do that in my original answer, but missed it out of the example snippet. The example above works for me.

Comment: i hadn't added `myzip.read()` before, but error is same after adding it too. Can you check if I'm opening the file with Javascript correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you debug your JavaScript. You should test the view without using JavaScript to work out where the problem is.